# Trying to use Javascript Function in AmCharts4 Barchart to convert number of days to years and months

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I am adding some charts to a **cakephp4** app using **amcharts 4**.

I have an **amCharts4** bar chart that shows the number of days that I need to convert to

```
<years> years, <months> months, <days> days
```

in my source data I have an "amount" column that contains the number of days, for example `500`. I need that to show up as `'1 year, 4 months, 15 days`. I am using a JS function `getFormatedStringFromDays(numberOfDays)` which works great.

I'm trying to set a var to be used in the function - I've tried `Number()`, `parseInt()`, etc. trying to get the `var mypreconvertednumber` to be seen as a number. Every attempt I
make produces `NaN`  - I can assign `mypreconvertednumber` a number (like `var mypreconvertednumber = 500;`) and of course it works fine.

My source data looks like this (`amount` is the number I'm trying to convert in the label):

```js
barchart1.data = [{
        "type": "Last Check In",
        "amount": 500
},

var mypreconvertednumber = "{values.valueX.workingValue.formatNumber('#')}";

var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
valueLabel.label.text = getFormatedStringFromDays(mypreconvertednumber);
valueLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "left";
valueLabel.label.fontSize = 10;
valueLabel.label.truncate = false;
valueLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
valueLabel.label.dx = 5;
```

I'm hoping someone can point me to an **amcharts** built-in function to process the value label text like in **amcharts 3**.

```js
"labelFunction": function(data) {
    return getFormatedStringFromDays(data);
},
```

I have been scouring the docs - and probably looked right past the option I need.
Thank you for any help any of you can give me to help solve this.

**The function works when I place a number like:**

```
getFormatedStringFromDays('500') // will return 1 year, 4 months, 15 days.
```

But when I try to use the `var mypreconvertednumber = "{values.valueX.workingValue.formatNumber('#')}";` the function returns `NaN` - ive tried using `Number()`, `parseInt()` to attempt to make sure its a number but always get `NaN`.

```
getFormatedStringFromDays(mypreconvertednumber) // produces NaN  - even though the source data amount is: 500 
barchart1.data = [{ "type": "Last Check In", "amount": 500 },...]
```

Comment: I don't understand - is the problem with amcharts or with converting the number of days to formatted string? The title says its the latter, but your post says the function you made works great.

Comment: Please precise where the problem occurs exactly. And if your problem is in fact with converting days to years and months, are you going to assume that 1 year is 365 days and 1 month is 30 days?

Comment: the function works when i place a number like getFormatedStringFromDays('500') and will return 1 year, 4 months, 15 days. but when i try to use the var mypreconvertednumber = "{values.valueX.workingValue.formatNumber('#')}"; the function returns NAN - ive tried using Number(), parseint() to attempt to make sure its a numebr but always get NAN

Comment: @RoboMop - the problem is with amcharts4 - i can statically place a value in that function and it will produce the coverted results label in the chart but when i try and use var mypreconvertednumber = "{values.valueX.workingValue.formatNumber('#')}";   getFormatedStringFromDays(mypreconvertednumber)  i always get NAN - i can use that var in the valueLabel.label.text =  mypreconvertednumber; and it returns the 500 expected value.. I hope this makes sense ??

Comment: Please show us in the post the code inside `getFormatedStringFromDays` as well as the result of calling `values.valueX.workingValue.formatNumber('#')`.

Comment: @RoboMop - fixed :-) using : valueLabel.label.adapter.add('text', function (x, target) {
        var values = target.dataItem.values;
        var showx = values.valueX.value
        return getFormatedStringFromDays(showx);
    });

Comment: Thank you guys - you inspired me to look deeper and i discovered the adapter to add to solve this ! Have a great one all !!!